# Does "Bonk! Atomic Punch" cancel out fall damage?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-scout

When under the effect of "Bonk! Atomic Punch" will the player still take fall damage?

Comment: The question is asking the opposite of the title, making them consistent would lend to easier reading.

Answer (score 8):

No, the player does not take damage in any form. You could say it is an equivalent of an ubercharge, except the scout cannot attack.

[Drinks Bonk and jumps](http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/577859993122345450/AB65CE3ED9D86F2B34E7749BBCC73D77F71126B3/)
[No damage taken from the jump](http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/577859993122346998/AB24178895205EAE32DFA5D80147E00180BC1406/)
[Same jump with no drink. Damage taken.](http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/577859993122348691/24F91A70DBFFCD993B2622F1DBC657852EBDEC63/)

Comment: I drink Bonk and jump.  :)

Comment: The Scout *can* attack by taunting if he has the appropriate weapon equipped, but he can't do so the conventional way (primary fire).